# MPAndroidChart - How to set description in another position?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

Is possible to place the position of the description of the chart in another position than in the bottom right corner of the chart?

I just have a BarChart where some bars on the right are zero and are in the same position as the description.

[image]

Comment: as I know, you can't change the position. But you can hide this, if you want.

Comment: @rguerra understand. that I wanted to show the total of all the bars in the description; but good.

Comment: Can you put a picture please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**v2 and lower**:

You can either hide the description by calling

```
chart.setDescription("");
```

or modify the position of the description by calling

```
chart.setDescriptionPosition(float xpos, float ypos)
```

**v3.0.0+** release:

```
mChart.getDescription().setText("X-Axis:  Date\\nY-Axis:Output ");
mChart.getDescription().setPosition(3f,3f);
```

[Here](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart-documentation/description/), you can find the official documentation for the Description.

Comment: How to set the text on the top?   i tried with c.drawText(mDescription, getWidth() - mViewPortHandler.offsetRight() - 10,
                getHeight() - mViewPortHandler.offsetTop()
                        - 900, mDescPaint);   but when the device rotate to landscape, the text do not show.

Comment: try with mViewPortHandler.contentTop() + Utils.calcTextHeight(mDescPaint, mDescription) for the y-coordinate

Comment: @PhilippJahoda What's this mViewPortHandler,mDescPaint, mDescription here??

Comment: @PhilippJahoda I didn't saw setDescriptionPosition() method for chart in MPAndroidChart v3.0.1.

Comment: @PhilippJahoda Please could you update your answer so it shows how to derive the correct values for `xpos` and `ypos` in order to position the description at the top right of the chart content area?

Comment: @KJEjava48, mViewPortHandler = chart.getViewPortHandler(), mDesPaint = chart.getPaint(Chart.PAINT_DESCRIPTION) and mDescription = is the text string =  chart.getDescription().getText()

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the description text that appears in the bottom right corner of the chart. I think that you can just disable this with (you can't change the position).

```
chart.setDescription(null);
```

or

```
chart.setDescription("");
```

Comment: Yes, you can change the position.

Comment: chart.setDescriptionPosition(float xpos, float ypos) changes position. Know your facts pls